# Keycloak: my secured resources are accessible without login

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, openid-connect, keycloak

I am trying to secure my sample web project using keycloak.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchems-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <display-name>Client</display-name>
    <description>
        Client App
    </description>

    <module-name>client</module-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Security contraint for /roles folder</display-name>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>Role pages</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/client/roles/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>valijon-demo</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "ourdemo",
  "public-client": true
}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve" />
</Context>
```

Application in the keycloak server:

> **Client ID :** ourdemo
>
> **Client Protocol** openid-connect
>
> **Access Type** public
>
> **Root URL** localhost:9595/client/*
>
> **Valid redirect uri** localhost:9595/client/*/*
>
> **Admin URL** localhost:9595/client/*

Keycloak is not securing the app. It lets access /client/roles/* without being logged in.

If I try to remove jars from **keycloak-tomcat8-adapter-dist-3.4.0.Final.zip** in *C:\tomcat8\apache-tomcat-8.0.47\lib* folder and access /client/roles/* I will get 500, server throws noshuchmethod exceptions(Which means keycloak is being used in the project).

> Can someone explain why /client/roles/*  is not being secured?

Comment: client "ourdemo"
Active Sessions: 0

Comment: I tried to change web.xml as below:

<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

It didn't work.

Comment: Followed all the steps from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.adoc

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @fandango I tried the same thing several times and it began working. Probably, I missed a tiny detail regarding IDE configuration

Comment: I also found the solution. It was just because Tomcat failed to contact the Keycloak server. Without any error in the log.